# Left join with where condition and use betwen operator two date column

Tags: mysql

I want to left join two table access_event_logs and hrm_personal_information its works perfectly.

```
 Query is:
        select concat(first_name," ",middle_name," ",last_name) as Name, 
        h.TIMESTAMPS, 
        a.PBI_ID 
        from 
        access_event_logs h LEFT JOIN hrm_personal_information a on h.USERID=a.PBI_ID 
        WHERE 1 group by DATE(h.TIMESTAMPS);
```

But i use where condition with between operator left join could not work .

```
   Query is:
    select concat(first_name," ",middle_name," ",last_name) as Name, 
    h.TIMESTAMPS, 
    a.PBI_ID 
    from 
    access_event_logs h LEFT JOIN hrm_personal_information a on h.USERID=a.PBI_ID 
    WHERE h.USERID=100032 and
    h.TIMESTAMPS between '2015-11-02' and '2016-11-20'
     group by DATE(h.TIMESTAMPS);
```

How can I solve it? please help me.

Comment: what is the format of `TIMESTAMPS` ?

Comment: Did you checked query without join like this : select * from access_event_logs h WHERE h.USERID=100032 and h.TIMESTAMPS between '2015-11-02' and '2016-11-20' group by DATE(h.TIMESTAMPS);. -- and is it working correctly?

Comment: select * from access_event_logs h WHERE h.USERID=100032 and h.TIMESTAMPS between '2015-11-02' and '2016-11-20' group by DATE(h.TIMESTAMPS);yes, its work perfectly

Comment: It is very strange for me. I can help if you create table and sample data on sqlfiddle.com and share its link here.

Answer (score 0):

as its timestamp you either need to convert timestamp field to date or add time in your comparison

like

```
date(h.TIMESTAMPS) between '2015-11-02' and '2016-11-20'
```

or

```
h.TIMESTAMPS between '2015-11-02 00:00:01' and '2016-11-20 23:59:59'
```

Comment: thank you dear , its works perfectly, but i would like to see data format is given below..    @KP                                                                      User ID Name Date
100032 Farid Ahammad 11/2/2015
100032 Farid Ahammad 11/3/2015
100032 Farid Ahammad 0000-00-00
100032 Farid Ahammad 11/5/2015
100032 Farid Ahammad 0000-00-00
100032 Farid Ahammad 11/7/2015
100032 Farid Ahammad 11/8/2015

Comment: its difficult to understand the format from the comment, you can update it in your question itself

Comment: also accept the answer if it works for you, which is the tick below the vote